# Как добавить в gitignore только одну строчку из файла?

Tags: git, gitignore

Хотел залить получившуюся программу в репозиторий, но при работе в программе используется база данных, пароль к которой не хотелось бы палить. Это значение занимает всего одну строчку и исключать из-за этого весь файл не хотелось бы т.к. написано довольно много. Возможно ли исключить из коммита ровно 1 строчку файла через gitignore? Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Дубликатом не является, в приведенном вопросе речь о другом...

Comment: @arrr [Can git ignore a specific line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557467/can-git-ignore-a-specific-line)

Comment: дубликатом является, потому что это то, как надо делать. Если даже был бы способ добавить в гитигнор определенную строчку, то эта строчка с вашим паролем все равно была бы в репозитории, только в другом файле

Answer (score 3):

Смотрите в сторону переменных окружений. В файл .env записываете пароль, сам файл помещаете в .gitignore. Находите библиотеку для вашего языка, которая преобразует содержимое .env в переменные окружения. Затем в коде получаете доступ к этой переменной.